# GNU PLOT 2D Curve

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gnu

I am trying to plot the following data:

```
    SMO LogiBoost   BFTree
25(>=7) 0.81    0.72    0.62
30(>=7) 0.83    0.76    0.56
35(>=7) 0.84    0.70    0.75
40(>=7) 0.74    0.67    0.58
25(>=8) 0.73    0.76    0.57
30(>=8) 0.78    0.74    0.65
35(>=8) 0.83    0.78    0.68
40(>=8) 0.75    0.67    0.66
25(>=9) 0.69    0.74    0.62
30(>=9) 0.79    0.75    0.62
35(>=9) 0.82    0.82    0.69
40(>=9) 0.78    0.80    0.53
25(>=12)    0.77    0.78    0.67
30(>=12)    0.76    0.74    0.59
35(>=12)    0.91    0.94    0.75
40(>=12)    0.75    0.75    0.64
25(>=15)    0.74    0.74    0.60
30(>=15)    0.80    0.71    0.64
35(>=15)    0.80    0.71    0.76
40(>=15)    0.75    0.75    0.75
SansVar(>= 7)   0.80    0.77    0.61
SansVar(>=8)    0.71    0.75    0.56
SansVar(>=9)    0.81    0.76    0.71
SansVar(>=12)   0.84    0.82    0.68
SansVar(>=15)   0.81    0.83    0.75
```

The first column represents the X labels and the 1st line represents the Y lables[image]

I tried to add the X labels also but they overlap each other, is it possible to fix it?
[image]

```
Command to plot:  plot "data1.txt" using 1:xtic(1) title 'SMO' with lines,\ "data.txt" using 2:xtic(1) title 'LogiBoost' with lines, \ "data.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title 'BFTree' with lines
```

I found maybe a solution which is the following, but still the problem si that the xlabels don't fit in the whole image.

```
set xtics rotate by -45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try resizing the margins.

```
reset
set terminal png
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.25  
set output 'out.png'  
set xtics rotate by -45 scale 0
plot "data.dat" using 1:xtic(1) title 'SMO' with lines, \ 
     "" using 2:xtic(1) title 'LogiBoost' with lines, \
     "" using 3:xtic(1) title 'BFTree' with lines
```

[image]